# How to display posts from another section with paging in HUGO?

Tags: hugo

I am trying to write code in “moto” list.html section. I would like to display all pages from “auta” section with paging. So, I need to display posts from another section with paging.

I use hugo v0.96.

I am not sure, why it’s not working with paging.

Not working code with paging:

```
{{ $cars := (where .Site.AllPages ".Section" "auta") }}

{{ $paginator := .Paginate $cars }}

{{ range $paginator.Pages}}

<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

     <h3 class="h6 text-uppercase mb-1"><a class="text-dark product-name" href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a></h3>

  </div>

  {{ end}}
```

Working code without paging:

```
{{ $cars := (where .Site.AllPages ".Section" "auta") }}

    {{ range $cars }}

<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

   <h3 class="h6 text-uppercase mb-1"><a class="text-dark product-name" href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a></h3>

  </div>

  {{ end}}
```

Where’s the problem?

Please, help me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. .Paginate can be only one time on same page.

I had .Paginate in header (out of this code). And it's not posibble override (by official docs of Hugo)